# mod_wsgi-express module-config issue

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I am trying to host the django 3.1(python3.8) app on window 10 with WAMP64 and mod_wsgi API.

Am able to preform the following command sucessfully.

1- set "MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR=C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46"

2- pip install mod_wsgi

And the next command which is "mod_wsgi-express module-config" is throwing below error.

'mod_wsgi-express' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Please help me with, what am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one : pip install `mod_wsgi-standalone`

from doc :

> When installing mod_wsgi-standalone, it will also install a version of
> Apache into your Python distribution. You can only use
> mod_wsgi-express when using this variant of the package. The
> mod_wsgi-standalone package follows the same version numbering as the
> mod_wsgi package on PyPi.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem,here is what worked for me.

Make sure you uninstalled the installed version of mod_wsgi first.

```
pip uninstall mod_wsgi
```

Double check you set MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR with forward slashes and using same case as file pathname actually uses. For example

```
MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR=C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.46
```

Then run

```
pip install --no-cache-dir mod_wsgi
```

Finally run

```
mod_wsgi-express module-config
```

Then copy the output into your Apache's httpd.conf

Restart Apache